# Rendering curved text in AndEngine

Tags: java, andengine, transformation

I'm trying to implement a small game using AndEngine and I have a question about the Text. More specifically, I'm wondering if it is possible to deform the text so that you can have a "curved" text or something like this.

I have searched on the Internet but I couldn't find an answer about this. I have seen that there exists a class Transformation in AndEngine but I don't know if its purpose is what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to render the font to a texture, and lay that texture onto an deformed strip of triangles.
But maybe somebody knows an easier way, idk

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it but since it is an optional feature I think I have better to do it without this effect and work on it later ^^

Answer (score 0):

The Text class is an Entity that has a VertexBuffer. If you want to transform the Text then just use a custom VertexBuffer with more vertices. If you have any questions concerning the calculation of the uv coordinates of the vertices to create the warp just ask.